# Multiple blocks in switch stat?

Tags: java, switch-statement

This Q rather looks for a verification.

The [Java docs on switch statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) reads like multiple `default` 
blocks are OK:

> The body of a switch statement is known as a switch block. A statement in the switch block can be labeled with one or more case or default labels. "

are there any case(s) that 2+ `default` blocks 
can exist in a `switch` stat? can't be to my knowledge. furthermore-- wouldn't make sense.

Comment: Check the docs.It doesn't say more than 1 default statement..

Answer (score 1):

The JLS is always the real reference:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.11

Notably, this:

> Given a switch statement, all of the following must be true or a
>   compile-time error occurs:
>
> - Every case constant associated with the switch statement must be assignment compatible with the type of the switch statement's
>     Expression (§5.2).
> - If the type of the switch statement's Expression is an enum type, then every case constant associated with the switch statement must be
>     an enum constant of that type.
> - No two of the case constants associated with the switch statement have the same value.
> - No case constant associated with the switch statement is null.
> - ***At most one default label is associated with the switch statement.***

It would likely be clearer with something less ambiguous, roughly:

> Switch block statements can be labeled with one or more `case` labels, or a single, optional `default` label.

Comment: your last stat. spoiling it-- i keep staring at it. pls edit so thta i can accept

Answer (score 0):

No. You can only have one default block in a switch statement.

```
int a = -1;
switch (a) {
case 0: System.out.println("zero"); break;
case 1: System.out.println("one"); break;
default: System.out.println("default");
}
```

If you added a second `default` it would be a compile time error.

Answer (score 0):

it's just saying you can have one or more labels and the 2 types of labels you can use are case and default. What it fails to clarify is that you can have multiple case and only one default label.

Answer (score 0):

***`A statement in the switch block can be labeled with one or more case or default labels`***

It never says it can have more than 1 default labels.Here "labels" is used in a plural form in conjunction with other case labels.

It is compile time error to declare more than 1 default statement

Comment: It's pretty misleading, though, since it can easily be interpreted as "can be labeled with (one or more) (case or default labels). It would be clearer as "labeled with one or more case labels, and no more than one default label".

Answer (score 0):

No, Even if you could do this a switch statement allows for more than one line of code to be executed so there would never actually be a use to have a statement be used twice when it only has to be used once.

Example of a switch statement executing more than one line of code:

```
switch (month){
        case 1: 
        monthString = "January"; 
        month = 2;
        System.out.println("It is " + monthString + " the " + month + "of the year");
        break;

        case 2: monthString = "February";
        break;
        }
```